# Hibernate CascadeType Issue: Updates not Cascading to Child Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, constraints, one-to-one, cascading

I'm encountering an issue with Hibernate when trying to update a parent entity that has a one-to-one relationship with a child entity. Specifically, I've configured CascadeType.ALL for the relationship, but when I update the parent entity, the changes are not cascading to the associated child entity.

Additional information:

- I'm using a separate Java module to perform database operations (i.e., I'm not using the DAO model).
- I properly configured bidirectional mapping between entities.

`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`

Here's how I've configured my entities:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // Other fields and annotations...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Child child;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // Other fields and annotations...

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    // Constructors, getters, and setters...
}
```

What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that update is reflected to both parent and child entity are properly cascaded?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Expectation:
My expectation is that since the two entities are bidirectionally mapped, when a parent entity is saved to the database, the child entity shall also be saved automatically. Additionally, when updating an existing row with function *session.saveOrUpdate(parentEntity)*, both the parent and child entities should be updated accordingly.

Analysis:
session.saveOrUpdate(parentEntity)
Above function works fine to create a new row with unique primary key.
But when i want to update the data in existing row of same primary key it throws:

Answer (score 0):

Try to swap the owning side:

1. Put `@JoinColumn` and `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` above Child field in Parent class
2. Put `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "child")` above Parent field in Child class

Are you using ddl-auto to create you database structure? Could you show table create scripts?

Make sure that you really need the bi-directional relationship